# Hey guys! I need to create an effect with 'hover' on several buttons in the CSS, but I can't. What do I do?

Tags: html, css, input

Well, I need applicable the effect ::hover in many buttons, but I don't know to do this. Look my code:

```
`.button-password-simples, .button-password-with-numbers, .button-password-shuffled, .chooser_button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    left: 10.5px;
    background-color: #121213c0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.856);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 11%);
}
`
```

Can seem strange, but this CSS connects that all the buttons haha

Ok! I accept suggestions for the updates and, the principal: solve my problem...

Thanks! <3

Comment: `.button-password-simples:hover, .button-password-with-numbers:hover,`....

Comment: Add :hover to your classes: .button-password-simples:hover, .button-password-with-numbers:hover, .button-password-shuffled:hover, .chooser_button:hover

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's the simplest way to achieve the hover effect. Be careful here, applying the same style on buttons with different attributes may lead to undesired results in your code functionality.

```css
.button-password-simples:hover, .button-password-with-numbers:hover, .button-password-shuffled:hover, .chooser_button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40px;
    left: 10.5px;
    background-color: #121213c0;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.856);
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 11%);
}
```

Comment: Perfect there!! <3